# Libgdx load texture from Gdx.files.external() showing as black rectangles

Tags: java, android, libgdx, filesystems

I have added both the external read and write permissions and requested permission for them from the user. I have used the libgdx file system to generate a list of filehandles of pictures I would like to load. I load them like this:

```
image = new Texture(fh); //fh is the filehandle
```

When I render any of the images I tried to load it just renders a black rectangle. I render them just using a spritebatch with the .draw method like I normally would. Any idea why they are rendering as black rectangles? Thanks in advance/

My image module code:

```
package com.ggi.uparty.ui;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import com.ggi.uparty.screens.ImagePicker;

public class ImagePickerModule {

public ImagePicker p;

public FileHandle fh;

public Texture image = null;

public TextureRegion load,preview;


public float theta = 0;

public Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle();

public ImagePickerModule(ImagePicker p, final FileHandle fh){
    theta = 0;
    bounds.width=.85f*Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/6f;
    bounds.height=bounds.width;

    load = new TextureRegion(p.u.assets.get("UI/Load.png", Texture.class));

    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
            //image = new Texture(fh);

            image = new Texture(fh);
            System.out.println(fh.path());
            float sqSize = image.getWidth()<image.getHeight()?image.getWidth():image.getHeight();
            preview = new TextureRegion(image,bounds.x+bounds.width/2-sqSize/2,bounds.y+bounds.height/2-sqSize/2,sqSize,sqSize);
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    });
    t.start();
}

public void draw(SpriteBatch pic,float fade){
    theta++;
    pic.setColor(1, 1, 1, fade);
    if(image == null){
        pic.draw(load, bounds.x+bounds.width / 2 - bounds.height / 4, bounds.y + bounds.height / 4+theta, bounds.height / 4,
                bounds.height / 4, bounds.height / 2, bounds.height / 2, 1, 1, -theta);
    }
    else{
        pic.draw(image,bounds.x,bounds.y+theta,bounds.width,bounds.height);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Probably context loss, but it's impossible to say from that 1 line of code.

Comment: @p.streef added the code with the loading and displaying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to load a texture on a non-ui thread. If you want async loading of textures use the assetmanager.

To test this, try changing the Thread.start to thread.run (run immediately in the thread you are on now, so disabling the thread) the image should load fine.

then to get async loading implement an assetmanager:

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets

Comment: thread.start did not work but using Gdx.app.postRunnable() did. Would like to use the asset manager but i didnt think it would load from external storage will look more into that thanks for the help!

Comment: @GoodGameIndustries Instantiate the AssetManager with an ExternalFileHandleResolver.

Comment: Good to know you got it to work! FYI: It should work if you do thread.run in stead of thread.start (basically running the runnable you created). With postRunnable you just run immediately as well (since you are on the UI thread) doing the same thing.